# Tensorboard doesn't display the graph (HTML error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I created Tensorboard logs with a graph, using the `tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py` script (I also have the same issue on other scripts).

```
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("logdir", graph_def=sess.graph_def)
```

The Tensorboard works well for Scalars, Images and Histograms, but not for graphs. I get a white page, with only the header.

If I open the browser console (*Firefox 42, Ubuntu 14.04*), I get those errors when I switch to the GRAPH tab:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:  tf-tensorboard.html-12.js:115:0
Reading graph.pbtxt : 2 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Reading stats.pbtxt : 0 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Parsing graph.pbtxt : 26 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Normalizing names : 10 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Building the data structure : 13 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Adding nodes : 14 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Detect series : 16 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Adding edges : 14 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
Finding similar subgraphs : 27 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
new tf.graph.render.Hierarchy : 17 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
tf-graph-scene (layout): : 214 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
tf-graph-scene (build scene): : 118 ms tf-tensorboard.html.js:13:1
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:  tf-tensorboard.html-12.js:115:0
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:  tf-tensorboard.html-6.js:76:0
TypeError: this.translate is undefined
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensorboard is only working in Google Chrome as far as I can tell. I tried Safari, Firefox and Chrome on my Mac and it only showed the graph properly in Chrome.